# IDE for Common Intermediate Language (CIL)

Tags: .net, ide, cil

Is there a some IDE for editing CIL-code? I'm looking for is specific IDE with embedded compiler/decompilder, syntax highlighting, embedded documentation etc.

ildasm+Sublime+ilasm is no good for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extesnsion to support IL: [IL Support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44034a7b-143d-4b51-b7bc-99aa656ba137)

Also take a look at [xacc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xacc/).

Answer (score 2):

Try SharpDevelop 3.xx (http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Download/#SharpDevelop3x), it provides syntax highlighting and automatic build, but
unfortunately it doesn't decompile existing assemblies.

You may also want to try Reflector with Reflexir plugin, but it functionality is rather limited...